GeoGebra Discovery
I'm a beginner with Ubuntu "using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS" and recently installed GeoGebra Discovery from the Snap store using the App Center. However, after the installation, I am unable to launch the application.
Can I get help!

Decribe what happens when you try. Also review your logs in /var/log/syslog at the time you tried, and look for logged errors.

The Snap Store web page for Geogebra-Discovery includes a link to their GitHub source which includes an issue tracker.
If you believe that the software is at fault (not an error or misconfiguration of your system), then please report your problem to their issue tracker with enough detail for them to reproduce the problem in their environment.
